# How to publish "web site" in the network?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, web, publish

I am using Visual Studio 2010, This is an ASP.NET web site,

I already finish my website. Now I'm trying to publish to the Internet or maybe in my office for others to see. How do I publish it? I tried Google but project and website are different method. I see project is easier and there are a lot of tutorials for it, but I'm using a website project.

Comment: Is it static HTML or is it a web app? Will you be hosting it in IIS or another web server?

Comment: This is an ASP.NET web site,

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVE 

our config file shouldn't be located on the dev desktop.. it should be within your website, and that website should be located somewhere within IIS (default location is c:\inetput\wwwroot\).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following links:

[ASP.Net Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) 
[VS2010 Web Deployment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx)

Comment: i got ISS in my server.. how do i connect it?

Comment: Check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/02/04/web-deployment-with-vs-2010-and-iis.aspx)